# Google App Script looping through array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I'm trying to loop through an array of values and If the any of the values is bigger than 0, then the script should send a specific email. I just cant figure it out how to do it. What am I doing wrong?

```
  var TO = ['email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com'];
  var failedOperation = [0, 0, 0, 52, 2, 5,]
  var message1 = 'Check the sheet';
  var message2 = 'Its Ok';
  var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';

  for(var i in failedOperation && var j in TO){
    if(typeof failedOperation[i] > 0){
      MailApp.sendEmail(TO[j], subject, message1);
    }
    else{
      MailApp.sendEmail(TO[j], subject, message2);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function www() {
  var TO = ['email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com'];
  var failedOperation = [0, 0, 0, 52, 2, 5];
  var message1 = 'Check the sheet';
  var message2 = 'Its Ok';
  var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
  for(var i=0; i<failedOperation.length;i++){
    if(failedOperation[i]>0){
      MailApp.sendEmail(TO[1], subject, message1);
    }else{
      MailApp.sendEmail(TO[0], subject, message2);
    }
  }
}
```